# How to preset $_POST for filter_input()?

Tags: php, post

Assuming this script:

```
<?php $_POST['user'] = 'test'; ?>
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $_POST['user']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) ?>">
```

Why doesn't the second input see the $_POST value set on the first line and how can we make it see it?

Comment: why not you just use ```filter_var()```.e.g.:```filter_var($_POST['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking for a reference as I have seen it in the past, but as you show, `INPUT_POST` does not use the `$_POST` superglobal array.  At least not the at the state that you have access to.  Since you are adding to `$_POST` this won't work, you would need to use:

```
<?php echo filter_var($_POST['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); ?>
```